# Excel Formula or VBA to convert year, month data to actual date

Tags: vba, excel, date

I have 2 columns (year and month). A sample data of year column A is `2015` at cell A2. A sample data of month column B is `Jun` at cell B2. I would like to convert these data to date format in column C to '2015-06-00` at cell C2. Is there a formula or Excel VBA to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, 2015-06-00 is actually 31-May-2015. If you supply zero as the day-of-the-month, you get the last day of the previous month. Typically you would set it for the first day of the month. Use the [DATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATE-function-B91BEF00-4B5B-4EE0-B80E-06E68B1DFF29) for this with **1** as the *day_num* parameter or the [DATEVALUE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEVALUE-function-b5bd5892-0c18-4c78-be4a-d7b5b3525e23) if you are stringing together text-that-looks-like-a-date.

```
=datevalue(B2 & " 1, " & A2)
```

With a three letter month in B2, you will have to translate that to a numerical month if you opt for the DATE function.

```
=DATE(A2, LOOKUP(B2, {"Apr","Aug","Dec","Feb","Jan","Jul","Jun","Mar","May","Nov","Oct","Sep"}, {4,8,12,2,1,7,6,3,5,11,10,9}), 1)
```

Comment: Thanks! it works wonderfully well. Will choose it as answer in 5 minutes time.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand the answer. & means concatenate string. But why do you need `" 1, "`? Why the comma?

Comment: Understand now. Make it appear like "Jun1, 1998"

Answer (score 0):

in cell C "=FECHA(A2;B2;1)" (spanish excell)